# how do i save an Access report (including a subreport) as an Excel-compatible file and a readable PDF?

Tags: excel, ms-access, pdf, export

I have an Access (Office 365) report defined. When I open it within the Access application I designed, it opens correctly displays fine. The application is related to processing healthcare data, so we want to keep a log of the info on the report by saving the report as a PDF (1st preference) or as an Excel file (secondary preference). The code creates the files, but there is no usable content in either file. When I try to open the excel file, I get the error "Cannot open the file because the file format extension is not valid.".  When I open the PDF file, it contains error info.

---

I have a button on a form. This is the event procedure.

```
Private Sub cmdRpt_Excel_Proc_Summary_Click()
        Call ExportReport("Rpt_FileProcessing_Summary", "Rpt_FileProc_Summary", acFormatXLS)
        Call ExportReport("Rpt_FileProcessing_Summary", "Rpt_FileProc_Summary", acFormatPDF)
End Sub
```

---

This is the code for ExportReport

```
Sub ExportReport(strQry As String, strOutFile As String, strOutType As String)
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim xlApp As Object, wkbk As Object
    Dim strMsg
    Dim strFileNm As String

    strFileNm = DEFAULT_FOLDER & strOutFile & "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd_hhnn")

    If strOutType = acFormatXLS Then
        strFileNm = strFileNm & ".xlsx"
    Else
        strFileNm = strFileNm & ".pdf"
    End If

    'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strQry, strOutType, strFileNm, , , , acExportQualityScreen
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strQry, strOutType, strFileNm, True

    If strOutType = acFormatXLS Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        With xlApp
            .Visible = True
            Set wkbk = .Workbooks.Open(strFileNm)
        End With
    End If
procDone:
    Set wkbk = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
Exit Sub

errHandler:
    strMsg = Err.Description
    MsgBox strMsg, vbExclamation, "Unanticipated Error"
    Resume procDone

End Sub
```

The error event never fires. The excel and pdf files get created, but I can't open the excel file, and the contents of the pdf file are:

[image: contents of PDF file]

Any help in diagnosing the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time

Comment: When i have the report open, i try to "print" the report to a PDF file (output driver is Microsoft to PDF).  I get the same file contents of the error message and no report data.  When i print to PDF from other Office products, i get valid PDF file of the content.  So i definitely think it is an Access issue, not the ability to create PDF files.

Comment: acFormatXLS is .xls, use acFormatXLSX for .xlsx.

Comment: @krish KM, I reveiwed my code based on your suggestion.  However, I found additional research that Access Reports cannot be saved as an XLSX format, but can be saved as XLS.  I'm not sure why.  I adjusted my code to acFormatXLS, and made sure I assigned the correct file extension (".xls"), and I got the code to work.  The excel doesn't look pretty, but the data is all there for cut & paste purposes.  If the user wants a pretty version of the report, they can use the PDF version.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the code to work properly after being pointed in the right direction by @krish KM and @Phillipp Stappert.  I ended up with 2 buttons on my form.  First button saves the report as an XLS-version of Excel file and opens it in Excel.  The second button saves the report as a PDF file and opens it in Chrome.  To get the PDF part to work, I changed the default program on my computer to be the Chrome browser (after the IT department installed it for me).  Both buttons create the respective files and automatically open the file, once it is created.  The final code is below.

```
Private Sub cmdRpt_Excel_Proc_Summary_Click()
    Call ExportReport("Rpt_FileProcessing_Summary", "Rpt_FileProc_Summary", acFormatXLS)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdRpt_PDF_Proc_Summary_Click()
    Call ExportReport("Rpt_FileProcessing_Summary", "Rpt_FileProc_Summary", acFormatPDF)
End Sub

Sub ExportReport(strQry As String, strOutFile As String, strOutType As String)
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim xlApp As Object, wkbk As Object
    Dim strMsg
    Dim strFileNm As String

    strFileNm = DEFAULT_FOLDER & strOutFile & "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd_hhnn")

    If strOutType = acFormatXLS Then
        strFileNm = strFileNm & ".xls"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strQry, strOutType, strFileNm, False
    Else
        strFileNm = strFileNm & ".pdf"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strQry, strOutType, strFileNm, , , , acExportQualityScreen
    End If

    If strOutType = acFormatXLS Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        With xlApp
            .Visible = True
            Set wkbk = .Workbooks.Open(strFileNm)
        End With
    ElseIf strOutType = acFormatPDF Then
        Application.FollowHyperlink strFileNm
    End If
procDone:
    Set wkbk = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
Exit Sub

errHandler:
    strMsg = Err.Description
    MsgBox strMsg, vbExclamation, "Unanticipated Error"
    Resume procDone

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another program to read those files, because MS Edge is sometimes a little bit strange. You could use FireFox to read .pdf

Can you open the Excel file?

Comment: thanks for that suggestion.  i was able to read the PDF with a different software.  had to have IT dept install it since Edge is the default, and end users like me don't have ability to install anything on computer.